# Global Find and Replace in Visual Studio With Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, visual-studio, replace

In My Project, I want to add CssClass to All asp:Buttons which don't have the CssClass attribute.How can I use regular expressions to search and replace All?

search and replace this

```
<asp:Button ID="buttonSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="buttonSearch_Click" />
```

into the following

```
<asp:Button ID="buttonSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="buttonSearch_Click"  CssClass="button-default" />
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? This is quite trivial, so it's hard to help you (besides just doing the work for you) unless we know which part you're having problems with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it with "regular" VS find/replace regexes because they don't support [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

You can do it using a special [plugin](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a41d37d0-4b42-43fe-a9ec-4c2eb22bfaeb/), though. It's called Regular Expressions Margin and supports .NET style regexes:

[image: Screenshot]

Search for

```
<asp:Button\b(?![^<>]*\bCssClass)([^<>]*)/>
```

and replace all with

```
<asp:Button\1 CssClass="button-default" />
```

Answer (score 1):

ok, I resolve it by myself.

ctrl+shift+H

find what

```
{\<asp\:Button(:b+<:w>=:q(\n)*)*}{(:b)*/*\>}
```

replace with

```
\1 CssClass="button-default" \2
```

Comment: Yes, it's a problem,But I can't find a Regular Expression to match the Button which it don't have the CssClass attribute. Do you have any idea? and In Visual Studio, the Regular Expression is different from the standard Regular Expression. Thanks! My English is not good enough to descript the problem which I met clearly .

Answer (score 0):

search for `<asp:Button` and replace it with `<asp:Button CssClass="button-default"` in whole of your project.

Comment: thanks,but some buttons already have the CssClass attribute. I want to search and replace the buttons which don't have the CssClass attribute.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Visual Studio now supports Find and Replace with Regular Expressions:
*https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-regular-expressions-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#capture-groups-and-replacement-patterns*

Microsoft says

> Visual Studio uses .NET regular expressions to find and replace text.

Before using Regular Expressions in the Find and Replace interface, you just have to make sure to press the "Regular Expressions" button (the buttons contains a symbol like this: .*):
[image: The "Find and Replace" interface, with regular expressions enabled]

Note: as shown in the picture, you can also press Alt + E to enable regular expressions in the Find and Replace interface!

You can find more informations about the regular expressions & the Find and Replace feature [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-regular-expressions-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)